# Spring Cloud DataFlow: access to application.jar

Tags: docker, spring-cloud-dataflow

Spring Cloud DataFlow (SCDF) deployed and runned in docker-container.

Applications deployed at localhost.

The task is to register applications in SCDF.

When I use this URI file:///${HOME}/IdeaProjects/file_read_maven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT,  where {HOME} is an element of absolute path at localhost, I receive in log "Error: Unable to access jarfile."

When I change location of application from localhost to container, in which SCDF is deployed, I receive the same result.

What may be the possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve local artifacts from your laptop from inside the running Docker daemon, you will have to mount the volume where the artifacts are hosted.

Either you can resolve from the mounted file-system or alternatively you can from the local Maven cache, as well.

More details [here](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker/#accessing-the-host-file-system).